# SHA256CryptoServiceProvider not working in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, cryptography, visual-studio-2015

I create cross-platform project Xamarin.Forms (shared) in Visual Studio 2015, add one page; and I need SHA256CryptoServiceProvider, but i have a problem:

> "Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'SHA256CryptoServiceProvider' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

MD5CryptoServiceProvider - working good.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace App1
{
    public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
    {
        public Page1 ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            SHA256CryptoServiceProvider sha256 = new SHA256CryptoServiceProvider();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=23348

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because this class... really doesn't exist. Why? Using Xamarin, you are using portable .NET which lacks some of the full .NET features. I'm afraid you need to use some external libraries like [PCLCrypto](https://github.com/aarnott/pclcrypto) to fulfill your needs, or implement it by yourself (this is what I've done when I needed hash function in my Xamarin App)